# How do I queue up more buildings/units for a city's production?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I can't seem to tell a city that I would like to produce thing #2 after it is done with thing #1. Shift + Click doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out; there's a checkbox near the center of the screen, along the bottom. You have to click on it to enable Production Queue.

Comment: :-) I was about to answer, then I saw this comment. You should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 10):

Nevermind, figured it out; there's a checkbox near the center of the screen, along the bottom. You have to click on it to enable Production Queue.